# Secure rest api using spring security - custom status codes

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, http-status-code-403, userdetailsservice

I am using spring security (4.0.0.M2) to secure my web application and also my rest api. everything works great. but I have one problem. I want to return http result 403 (forbidden) instean of 401, when user could not be authenticated

I defined different http definitions, for each authentication scenario, one for web and one for api.

```
<http pattern="/rest/v?/**" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
    disable-url-rewriting="true" authentication-manager-ref="tokenAuthenticationManager" 
    create-session="stateless" realm="API security check"
    entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/v?/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />   
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic />
</http>

<authentication-manager id="tokenAuthenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="tokenUserDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>

public class TokenUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String checkUser)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        // lookup user
        if (user == null) {
            // here I whant to return 403 instead of 401
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Could somebody help to return http status code 403 in this case?

Thank you for help.

Best regards

sonny

Answer (score 0):

The [`BasicAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java) which is created by the `<http-basic>` element also has a reference to an entry point. It invokes this when authentication fails and this is where the 401 code comes from (which is normal with Basic authentication).

If you want to change it you can use the [`entry-point-ref`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http-basic) namespace attribute. So

```
<http-basic entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint" />
```

should give the result you want.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But it does not work. As you can see in my first posting, I allready using the http403EntryPoint as entry-point-ref. But when UsernameNotFoundException is thrown or loadUserByUsername returns null, this entry point is not called.

Comment: That is the entry point which is used in the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`. You haven't set the basic authentication reference. Check my answer again and read the linked docs.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I found out a working solution. When I use a custom filter (position=pre_auth), then I could change the response code using doFilter method.

But I am not sure, if this is really the best solution.